# $_POST[$variable] does not work

Tags: php, post

For input form I need random input name and id

I created random values 
    $token_hash = random

Then input field

```
 <input type="hidden" name="' .$token_hash .'" id="' .$token_hash .'" value="some_value">
```

Next above input form is php code to check what values get from form

```
 echo $_POST[$token_hash] .' $_POST[$token_hash]<br>';
```

Problem is that `$_POST[$token_hash]` echo blank value (no value)....

I tried also `$_POST[' .$token_hash .']` but do not work.

Other `$_POST` works, but they are like `$_POST['some_value']`

---

Seems finally get solution. Do not understand why it did not work before. If useful for someone else. Here is solution.

Create random value
    $token_hash = sha1(uniqid($time_when_form_submitted .'token' .$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]));

Then create session
    $_SESSION['token_hash'] = $token_hash;

Then pass session to input

```
echo '<input type="hidden" name="' .$_SESSION['token_hash'] .'" id="' .$_SESSION['token_hash'] .'" value="' .$_SESSION['token'] .'">'
```

Then get session value from input. **This code must be above all previos**
    $token_hash_from_input = $_SESSION['token_hash'];

Then with 
    $_POST[$token_hash_from_input])
get input value

Comment: On each request $token_hash will be set to a **different** random value

Comment: `var_dump($token_hash, $_POST)` and see what you have there... maybe `$token_hash` gets regenerated in the script you are posting into and they simply not matching?

Comment: May be you can not sending anything accessible from `$_POST['random']`

Comment: Thank you for answer Laimoncijus. I get this NULL array(7) { ["username"]=> string(0) "" ["email"]=> string(0) "" ["password"]=> string(0) "" ["confirm_password"]=> string(0) "" ["registration_time"]=> string(19) "2013-02-28 08:16:49" ["4948d875c320bef4af1fb5fcb646853a9fa05be0"]=> string(40) "f6f0f6264d3a96bcb1c332d1937bdd0de3aa534c" ["register"]=> string(8) "Register" } But.... at the moment I understand nothing...

Comment: your `$token_hash` is empty in the script you are making POST into...

Comment: From view source I see that it is not empty <input type="hidden" name="bf9af8b6eae7ebcadd58bd0a4d7fa18927c5eab4" id="bf9af8b6eae7ebcadd58bd0a4d7fa18927c5eab4" value="134c66b7af03b145c4c2cbc25b7935129defbf53"> But in $_POST empty

Answer (score 2):

You want the name of the input to be 'token_hash' and the value to be your random value.

```
<input name="token_hash" value="<?php echo $token_hash; %>" type="hidden" />
```

Now you can access the token hash on form submit:

```
$token_hash = $_POST['token_hash'];
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, but I need that instead name="token_hash" is name="$something_random" and then $_POST[$something_random] to get value="<?php echo $token_hash; %>"

Comment: Why? What do you get by doing it that way?

Comment: If I have name="email" then suppose all bots "know" that in this field must enter email. If for email field I have not random value name="34tYetc" then human at first check that 34tYetc is email, then may program bot accordingly. But if field value changes on each page load, then it is more difficult to program (i suppose)

Comment: Ah... interesting. First of all it's pretty hard to prevent bots from submitting cruddy data. However, I like Musa's answer.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need something like sessions to persist values across requests, e.g.

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['token_hash'] = $token_hash;
```

then retrieve it in the next page

```
session_start();
$token_hash = $_SESSION['token_hash'];
```

Answer (score 1):

@All I assume the questioner wants to have a random post field name and value

---

Note that the value of `$token_hash` will change on each request. There is no persistance unless you save that value in a session or database. I don't what exactly you are trying to do so its hard to give advices.

But this code example may show how to access a random `$_POST` index:

```
<input type="hidden" name="token_<?php echo uniqid();?>" value="<?php uniqid()?>" />
```

Then get the value using foreach:

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
    if(strpos($key, 'token_') !== FALSE) {
        echo 'the token is ' . $value;
    }
}
```

Comment: That's a bit clumsy way to do it. But it would work.

Comment: :) Feel free to edit or extend the post if you want

Comment: Actually if he would really want to have random-generated NAME attribute, this is a good approach. But dunno why he'd want to do that. It's better to post random value in value attribute.

Comment: I assumed he wants to do both random name and value.

Comment: I try to prevent bots to post. Like here http://nedbatchelder.com/text/stopbots.html

Comment: @user2118559 Read the article. (mostly) My code example should do the job

Comment: That means you could use this technique, yes. But try to make it a function so you can use it a bit easier instead of posting a foreach all the time.

Comment: At the moment have not found solution. Do not understand why $_POST[$token_hash] has no value at all....

Comment: I've mentioned this : *Note that the value of $token_hash will change on each request. There is no persistance unless you save that value in a session or database.* This means one the first request you create the form and send it to the browser. When the form is submitted (second request) $token_hash isn't defined anymore..

Comment: Yes, they change. So create $token_hash. Then pass $token_hash to session. Then in input field $_SESSION['token_hash']. How can I get the $_SESSION['token_hash'] value from input field? Something like $_POST[$_SESSION['token_hash']]. But what is correct code for $_POST?

Answer (score 0):

you need to do it like this,

```
$_POST["token_hash"]
```

if that `token_hash` has really been posted, you will get one

Comment: He has token_hash as a variable somewhere. The name is dynamic.

Comment: The name of the post is a random variable

Comment: That means he can't always access it with $_POST['token_hash'] ?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're generating a random value, you can't expect $_POST[$token_hash] to work.

When you POST your form, your PHP is random generating your $token_hash value AGAIN. So you should put your random generated value in a "value" attribute.

```
     <input name="token_hash" value="<?php echo $token_hash; ?>" type="hidden" />
```

and you can get it with $_POST['token_hash'] when you post your form.